# Cannot execute SpringBoot endpoint on Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest, tomcat

I developed a following endpoint using SpringBoot:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1")
public class UserResource {

    @GetMapping("users")
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getUsers() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(List.of(new User("George", "Walker")));
    }

}
```

The endpoint works when I launched it using `bootRun` Gradle task.

The endpoint can be reached using: `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users`

[image]

Then I build a war file using `war` Gradle Task and I deploy it using Tomcat.

[image]

I try to reach the same endpoint using the URL: `http://localhost:8080/user-service-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain/api/v1/users`, but it fails. The Tomcat is up, the app is deployed, but the endpoint is not accessible.

In addition to that I have in `build.gradle` entry: `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat` and a class:

```
package net.bean.userserviceapi;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(UserServiceApiApplication.class);
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: if you do not add any customisation, the context path in Tomcat is the name of the jar file.

Have you tried to extend SpringBootServletInitializer?

Comment: Please provide the details of the error you're getting while reaching the endpoint .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that I tried to run it on Apache Tomcat 10. It runs smoothly on Tomcat 9.

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.traditional-deployment

The first step in producing a deployable war file is to provide a SpringBootServletInitializer subclass and override its configure method. Doing so makes use of Spring Framework’s servlet 3.0 support and lets you configure your application when it is launched by the servlet container.

Comment: My bad. I had the additional configuration from the beginning. I mean: `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat` in `build.gradle` which allows me to execute `war` task and class `ServletInitializer` which implements `SpringBootServletInitializer`. However it still doesn't work. I thought that I maybe have wrong path in bowser.

Answer (score 1):

*first step*: is to configure your maven file to generate a `war` package.

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

*second step*: is to make your main class extends `SpringBootServletInitializer`

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Check this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.traditional-deployment) for more details.

Comment: My bad. I had the additional configuration from the beginning. I mean: `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat` in `build.gradle` which allows me to execute `war` task and class `ServletInitializer` which implements `SpringBootServletInitializer`. However it still doesn't work. I thought that I maybe have wrong path in bowser.